# Unified Swift API: use of undeclared type T

Tags: swift, generics, type-resolution

I am following John Sundell's post (https://www.swiftbysundell.com/posts/providing-a-unified-swift-error-api) on using a nice `perform` function to create a unified error API

```
func perform(_ expression: @autoclosure () throws -> T,
                orThrow error: Error) throws -> T {
    do {
        return try expression()
    } catch {
        throw error
    }
}

func someFunction(url: URL) throws -> Data {
    ...
    return try perform(Data(contentsOf: url), 
                       orThrow: SearchError.dataLoadingFailed(url))
}
```

But it gives me `Use of undeclared type` error at `T`. Isn't Xcode supposed to figure out type T by looking at the return type of the function passed in?

Comment: That `error` param should also use `@autoclosure`, which enables lazily evaluation. That way, you don't waste time running potentially expensive error-capturing code, only to not need to throw the resulting error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare any type parameters used in your function signature:

```
func perform<T>(
    _ expression: @autoclosure () throws -> T,
    orThrow error: Error
) throws -> T { ...
```

Comment: Thanks, do I have to add it to all functions that take generics?

Comment: @JGuo Nope. Generic functions that exist within generic types can reference the generic type parameters of their enclosing generic type. (e.g. `struct Box<T> { func get() -> T { ... } }`